# How to update ApplicationBar icons on phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons

For some reason I can't update the ApplicationBar icons when I make any changes to them.  For example, I'll edit appbar.save.rest.png or even replace it with another icon (but keep the same name) and recompile my project, expecting to see the new icon on the app bar, but it doesn't change.

This happens both, on the phone and on the emulator.  The only way I've found to "fix" this is to uninstall and reinstall the app, and even then it doesn't always work.

I have the Build Action set to "Content" and Copy to Output set to "Copy always" for all the icons so I have no idea why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Mind showing the XAML for the appbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit like a caching issue. Have you tried a clean then rebuild all, checking that all the files are updated?